# Is it possible to create load-balancer for fall-back instance in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to create an compute engine instance that will get all the traffic (100%). In case that the instance died, I want the instance te restart itself.

During that time of the restarting, I want another compute engine instance to get the traffic.

I want to use Google HTTP load-balancer.

Is it possible?

**In other words:** How to send traffic to instance b, white instance a not responding by using google cloud load-balancer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving HTTP traffic from your VM, you can configure HTTP load balancer. HTTP load balancer distributes the request to backend VMs based on round-robin algorithm. This can be overridden by configuring [session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#session_affinity). When session affinity is configured all the requests from the same client are sent to the same VM instance, as long as the instance stays healthy and has capacity. Once an instance is unhealthy or is out of capicity all the requests are sent to the other VM instances in the group. Detailed information on HTTP load balancer can be found on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#overview).

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question, yes it's completely possible. you will need a load balancer, health checks, possibly a VPN, or this could be achieved by clustering, you can use free software, cloud services, proprietary hardware. you will need to start investigating and ask a more specific question about something you are attempting.

Comment: I can do it with any software I want, the question is if Google load-balancer have this option?

Comment: maybe take the time to phrase your question in such a way as it is understandable, the answer is still yes it has a load balancer - we don't even know what service you are attempting to load balance - google cloud load balancer maybe completely inappropriate - *services* are load balanced not computers.

Comment: I edit the question. I try to load balancer a normal http traffic to compute engine instance